# Will atlas search indices from source instance work on atlas data federation instance?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

We are using atlas data federation and want to query data from it. There is no index option on data federation ui so I was wondering if indices created on source cluster will have positive impact on data federation instance resulting in faster query processing?

Answer (score 1):

Atlas Data Federation will push queries down to the underlying cluster where possible.  In these instances the Cluster can take advantage of indexes where applicable to the section

Comment: Maybe that is why i was getting slow (30+ sec) response.  When I ran queries directly on source,  it was much much faster (<=1 sec)

Comment: That should not result in slow responses.  It's possible that other factors may be contributing.  If you are querying using Atlas Data Federation in any one of the supported Data Federation regions your latency should be very similar to the direct to cluster query latency.  It could be something inherent in your query if it is federating over multiple clusters, an issue with the network or topologies (e.g. multiple regions), or a bug.